# Drawing a home icon

Tags: adobe-illustrator, icon

I want to design myself 4 simple, minimalistic icons, kind of like this:

[image: target icon]

I looked on YouTube, and saw that most videos do a sort of grid, so I tried to follow. This is what I've got:

[image: progress]

The "roof" of the house, is just two lines that I drew, how can I connect them to the rectangle at the bottom and get rid of the top side of the rectangle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use the **Shape Builder tool**.

[image]

Select all and drag from the triangle to the shape below with the Shape Builder Tool. 
This will combine both shapes into one.

[image]

You could also select all and click the 
**Unite** button on the **Pathfinder Panel** 
(`Window > Pathfinder`)

Comment: I didn't know how to create a triangle shape that would fit on top of the rectangle, so I drew two lines instead. Because I have two lines, I can't use the shape builder tool

Comment: @J86 simply select the 2 lines and choose `Object > Path > Join` from the menu, **twice**. The first time will join the 2 lines into 1 path. The second time will connect the two end anchors, forming a closed triangle... then use the answer above.

Comment: Thanks @Scott, I just tried and I got: https://imgur.com/a/b1drgaq

Comment: You appear to have the rectangle below *also* selected. You don't want the rectangle selected.

Comment: I see! I tried without the rectangle and I see got the same message: https://imgur.com/a/mqhurNi

Comment: Are you certain it's not *already* a closed trianlge? Perhaps you only needed to Join once because the two lines were *already* connected? Try the Shape Builder tool now...

Comment: Damn, you were right! thank you very much!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what tutorial you followed, but there is a much easier and quicker way.

Enable the grid and snap to grid

Then use the Pen Tool to make one closed shape.

Example:

[image]

Comment: Damn, you’re right, that is much easier!